# Need to save data before delete and re-insert

Tags: oracle, constraints, primary-key

I have to change the existing table as follows.

1. Drop the existing PRIMARY KEY
2. Add a NEW PRIMARY KEY

In this regard, I have to delete all the existing data before creating a new primary key. I then need to re-insert the data. The table is existing in multiple schemas and I need a query or PL/SQL block that will perform this function.

I used following queries:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA1.A DROP CONSTRAINT PK_A;

ALTER TABLE SCHEMA1.A ADD PID VARCHAR2(40 CHAR);

ALTER TABLE SCHEMA1.A ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY (PID));
```

It is failing at the last query with

```
ORA-01449: column contains NULL values; cannot alter to NOT NULL
```

Comment: Why do you need to delete the data? And do you have foreign key references to your primary key?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: When adding a primary key constraint, the statement is not getting executed mentioning that "ORA-01449: column contains NULL values; cannot alter to NOT NULL" .

Comment: How is the table existing in multiple schemas?

Comment: the table A is mentioned with the same name in multiple schemas as schema1.A, schema2.A, schema3. A etc. I need to execute a query or prog that will successfully alter the table in all schemas

Comment: You have to populate your new PID column with a update before you can make it the PK. You haven't said how you want to generate that though -  presumably not from a sequence since it's a string column. You'd need to do that with a delete/insert too, but an update is a more obvious approach.

Comment: The very first thing you need to do is decide how you are going to convert those NULLs into actual values. Even if you manage to copy the data somewhere else and delete it... you are going to get errors inserting the data with NULLs and a PK for that column

Comment: The new primary key is for maintaining the standards and good practice and doesn't have any special significance in my case. The existing data when being re-inserted into the table can have some random value in the newly added primary key column.

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic; it's a synthetic key? But why not just update the new column with random values in that case?

Comment: or better: make it a number field and use a sequence to populate it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to drop a table or any object among multiple schemas from a single DROP statement. You can use the below mentioned PL/SQL but be careful in using it and is possible include WHERE CLAUSE where possible.

```
SET serveroutput ON;  

DECLARE  

            CURSOR c    IS   

    SELECT username FROM dba_users;

  table_check_cnt NUMBER;


  dropSQL         VARCHAR2(300);

BEGIN  
  dbms_output.put_line('Execution of block starts');   
  FOR c1 IN c   
  LOOP   
    SELECT COUNT(*)   
    INTO table_check_cnt   
    FROM dba_tables   
    WHERE owner       =c1.username   
    AND table_name    ='FOO';    
    IF table_check_cnt=1 THEN   
      dbms_output.put_line('count is '||table_check_cnt);   
      dropSQL := 'drop table '|| c1.username || '.FOO';   
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dropsql;   
    END IF;   
  END LOOP;   
END;
```

And for the ORA-01449 error there is a null record present on the field on which we are creating the Primary constraint so remove the null value for every record in this field and it should be unique also.